# Join and null values data to the pivot table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, pivot

Having little trouble with SQL. What i am trying to do is to count different status and show it as pivot table. Code:

```
SELECT TAIL_NO,
       isnull(pt.A_GR_ST,0) as A_GR_ST,
       isnull(pt.O_R_LR_FLTS,0)
 FROM (select distinct
                X."Tail_#" as TAIL_NO,
                COUNT(*) as qty,
                X.statuss
         FROM X
        group by X.Tail_#, X.statuss) p    
PIVOT
 (
  MAX([qty])
  FOR [statuss] In([A_GR_ST], [O_R_LR_FLTS])
 ) As pt
order by TAIL_NO
```

Works perfect to me and gives output:

```
 TAIL_NO   A_GR_ST    O_R_LR_FLTS
--------- ---------  -------------
 RUD       0          1
 EW        7          2
 ED        100        10
```

Each status number (A_GR_ST, O_R_LR_FLTS) can be split deeper by day count: 0-1d,2-5d
What i want to do is to incorporate these days split into existing pivot table to see split status results by day count and if there is none days, i have to see zeros in table. Output should be like this:

```
 TAIL_NO    DAYS   A_GR_ST   O_R_LR_FLTS
--------- ------- --------- ------------- 
 RUD       0-1d    0         0
 RUD       2-5d    0         1
 EW        0-1d    7         2
 EW        2-5d    0         0
 ED        0-1d    40        3
 ED        2-5d    60        7
```

**How can it be done?** Thank you in advance.

When i use code:

```
SELECT TAIL_NO, 
       days,
       isnull(pt.A_GR_ST,0) as A_GR_ST,
       isnull(pt.O_R_LR_FLTS,0)
FROM (select distinct
               X."Tail_#" as TAIL_NO,
               COUNT(*) as qty,
               X.statuss,
               X.days
        FROM X
       group by X.Tail_#, X.statuss, X.days) p
PIVOT
 (
  MAX([qty])
  FOR [statuss] In([A_GR_ST],  [O_R_LR_FLTS])
 ) As pt
order by TAIL_NO
```

I get an output:

```
 TAIL_NO    DAYS   A_GR_ST   O_R_LR_FLTS
--------- ------- --------- ------------- 
 RUD       2-5d    0         1
 EW        0-1d    7         2
 ED        0-1d    40        3
 ED        2-5d    60        7
```

Which does not include zero lines. And i need to have them.

Comment: `isnull` is not a valid function in oracle. You should use `nvl` or `coalesce`.

Comment: Where is the `JOIN` in your anchor query? I can't see any `join` there?

Comment: Florin, i know what to use in Oracle, here is a sample from SQL Server thats why nvl left, but the question remains the same.

Comment: Mahmoud, what join do you want to see? in my X table there is a case written that if day difference is between 0-1 it shows '0-1d' and else it shows '2-5d'. So if there is no record between some time frame data is not shown(as in RUD tail no example where it has no values between '0-1d',but i want to see that it was none and see 0 in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate your missing lines. An ideea would be:

```
select 
  a.tail_no,
  a.statuss,
  days.days
  nvl(orig.qty, 0) as qty
from 
    (SELECT 
       X."Tail_#" as TAIL_NO, X.statuss
     FROM X
     GROUP BY X.Tail_#, X.statuss
     )a
   cross join (select distinct days from x) days
   left join (
       SELECT 
          X."Tail_#" as TAIL_NO,
          X.statuss,
          X.days,
          COUNT(*) as qty
        FROM X
        GROUP BY X.Tail_#, X.statuss, X.days
        ) orig
       ON a.tail_no = orig.tail_no and a.statuss=orig.statuss and a.days=orig.days
```

and then continue with an pivot query over this query.

Comment: THANK YOU!! that's what i really need,somehow not thought about about cross join :) just minor adjustment to code last line,should be:  days.days=orig.days, not  a.days=orig.days as output from A, does not have days variable

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE and by performing some joins, this can be achieved:

```
with table_main as (
        SELECT TAIL_NO, DAYS, pt.A_GR_ST, pt.O_R_LR_FLTS
        FROM (select distinct
                      X."Tail_#" as TAIL_NO,
                      COUNT(*) as qty,
                      X.statuss,
                      X.DAYS as DAYS
                      FROM X
                     group by X.Tail_#,X.statuss,X.days) p

                PIVOT
                 (
                  MAX([qty])
                  FOR [statuss] In([A_GR_ST],  [O_R_LR_FLTS])
                    ) As pt
                  order by TAIL_NO),
table_days as (select d.days, t.tail_no from (
                    (select '0-1d' as days union all
                     select '2-5d') d
               cross join (select distinct TAIL_NO from table_main) t))
select td.DAYS, td.TAIL_NO, isnull(tm.A_GR_ST, 0), isnull(tm.O_R_LR_FLTS, 0)
  from table_days td
  left outer join table_main tm
  on tm.DAYS = td.days and tm.TAIL_NO = td.TAIL_NO;
```